# How to display automatically interactive plots in Atom/Juno using PyPlot and Julia

Tags: matplotlib, julia, atom-editor, interactive, juno-ide

I'm using Atom/Juno as IDE for my Julia programming.
I use `PyPlot` for graphical representation of plots however I noticed two important aspects (I'm migrating from MATLAB)

1- figures do not appear automatically after running julia scripts but only after typing `PyPlot.display_figs()` in the `REPL`.

2- figures displayed in Atom are not interactive.

On the contrary, if I open Julia `REPL` from terminal and I run the same code an interactive window appears (only after typing `PyPlot.display_figs()`).
Can I use Atom and have interactive plots to appear automatically at the end of each script without everytime using the `REPL`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Disable in built Atom plot Pane
2. Use interactive plotting backend (plotlyjs could be the best option)

Ad.1.

Go in Atom to Seetings->Packages->Julia Client->UI Options and disable the "Enable plot pane" option. Restart Atom.

Ad.2.

With the "Enable plot pane" turned on try running this code:

```
using Plots
plotlyjs()
Plots.plot(sin.(0:0.1:7))
```